# Difference between indexing operator ([]) of string and string_view

Tags: c++, c++17

`C++17` has given us `string_view` to optimise the scenarios where we were needlessly allocating memory when we only need a view of the underlying sequence of characters. The wisdom is that you can almost always replace `const std::string&` with `std::string_view`. Consider the following example:

```
char foo(const std::string& str)
{
    return str[0];
}
```

The above is a valid function for all values of `std::string`. However, if we change this to:

```
char foo(std::string_view sv)
{
    return sv[0];
}
```

We have triggered Undefined Behaviour for strings of size 0! [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator_at) has a note at the end:

> Unlike std::basic_string::operator[], std::basic_string_view::operator[]
>   (size()) has undefined behavior instead of returning CharT().

Does anyone know why the behaviour is incongruous for the indexing operator?

Comment: Isn't the former `str[0]` also undefined, same as `*begin()` or `front()`?

Comment: This was my TIL. `str[0]` was undefined in `c++03`. However, in `c++11` for `pos == size()`, a reference to character with value CharT() is returned. More details here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: "The wisdom is that you can almost always replace const std::string& with std::string_view" <== source?

Comment: @xaxxon I'd call that common sense. Unless another compelling reason for the existence of `string_view` comes to mind

Comment: @PasserBy For instance if you need something nul terminated... Or you need something that's not const...

Comment: I wish I could share a picture here!

From "Modern C++ Programming Cookbook" by Marius Bancila:
"You should use std::string_view to pass a parameter to a function, instead of std::string const & unless your code needs to call other functions that take std::string parameters"

Comment: @skgbanga that's a far cry from "you can almost always replace" it

Comment: fair enough. In your answer to @PasserBy you said "you need something that's not const", but in the question I said "const std::string&" so that is out of the consideration.

Comment: I would be very dubious of code that relied on the ability to dereference a zero length string. It should probably be protected by *asserts* regardless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is a std::string is guaranteed to be NUL terminated - a view is not.  Therefor a std::string always has a valid value at the 0th position.

For a std::string:

> If pos == size(), a reference to the character with value CharT() (the null character) is returned.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: I think you have correctly answered the reason for difference, and I will be slightly more sceptic now when replacing `const &` with `string_view`. Also a slight typo in your answer. NULL instead of NUL

Comment: @skgbanga the character terminating the string is the character NUL `\0`

Comment: You are right! http://www.asciitable.com I always used to call it NULL (and used to think they have overloaded the word).

Comment: @skgbanga if it works to just put a string_view in, then great.  but if you find yourself having to work around it to get specific behaviors that std::string has, just don't feel like you're doing the wrong thing to just go back to a std::string const &